# Implementing IEndpointBehavior for extending Bindings

Tags: c#, wcf

Is it possible to change the value of the properties of an [ConnectionOrientedTransportBindingElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.connectionorientedtransportbindingelement.connectionbuffersize.aspx) (e.g. ConnectionBufferSize) via an IEndpointBehavior implementation?

```
var host = new ServiceHost(typoef(ISomeService), new Uri(service));
var endpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof (ISomeService), new NetTcpBinding(), string.Empty);
endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new MyCustomEndpointBehavior());
// ...

class MyCustomEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior {
    // ....
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters) {
         // what to do here?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use behavior to modify binding internals. You need to construct custom binding via config or via code

```
 <customBinding>
  <binding name="MyCustomBinding">
   <binaryMessageEncoding />
   <tcpTransport connectionBufferSize="256192" maxOutputDelay="00:00:30" transferMode="Streamed">
   </tcpTransport>
  </binding>
 </customBinding>
```

Or Code

```
var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1), new Uri("net.tcp://someservice"));

            //binding stack - order matters!
            var myCustomNetTcpBindingStack = new List<BindingElement>();

            //session - if reliable
            var session = new ReliableSessionBindingElement();
            myCustomNetTcpBindingStack.Add(session);

            //transaction flow
            myCustomNetTcpBindingStack.Add(new TransactionFlowBindingElement(TransactionProtocol.OleTransactions));


            //encoding
            myCustomNetTcpBindingStack.Add(new BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement());

            //security
            //var security = SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();
            //myCustomNetTcpBindingStack.Add(security);

            //transport
            var transport = new TcpTransportBindingElement();
            transport.ConnectionBufferSize = 64 * 1024;
            myCustomNetTcpBindingStack.Add(transport);


            var myCustomNetTcpBinding = new CustomBinding(myCustomNetTcpBindingStack);

            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), myCustomNetTcpBinding, string.Empty);

            host.Open();
```

Good post about the ConnectionBufferSize [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2009/07/17/tuning-connectionbuffersize.aspx)